# Domain Specific URL include() exemption

Tags: apache, include, php

I want to allow a URL to be put inside php's include(); but only certain domains - not every one.  The other domains are owned by me, and on a separate server.  If someone tries to include() any other domain bu these I want them disallowed.

If this is not possible, is there a work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation?  Don't do it with includes.  Executing code in that fashion is like swallowing a chocolate covered cherry bomb.

Comment: how would you recommend avoiding chocolate covered cherry bombs?

Answer (score 0):

```
$allowed_domains = array(
      'stackoverflow.com',
      'www.stackoverflow.com',
      'facebook.com',
      'www.facebook.com',
      'google.com',
      'www.google.com',
    );

    if(!in_array(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST), $allowed_domains)) {
      // throw an error
    }
```

Comment: does this need to be in each file that needs the include() or can I put it somewhere where it checks for every php file on the server?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it on the web server so you don't even let the domain which is not allowed to parse or get any files. you have to remember any request will go through the web server and server static content or be parsed which all takes time and then add the time for the PHP script to execute.